# ubuntu を USB にインストールしてそこからブートさせることはできるか

Tags: macos, ubuntu

質問:

- ubuntu を USB にインストールしてそこからブートさせることはできますか？

環境:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Mac OS X El Capitan

やったこと:

MacBookAir と USB*2 を用意して、次を実行しました。

1. 公式のインストーラー ISO を USB に焼く
2. インストーラー USB をブートし、もう一つの USB (以下、対象USB) に向かって ubuntu インストール実行
3. インストールが終わった段階で、インストーラー USB を抜いて、対象 USB のみがささった状態でブート対象を選択する方法で PC 再起動 (起動時に <kbd>alt/option</kbd>長押し) しても、 ubuntu の USB は表示されません。

Comment: 実際にはOSXは関係ないのですが、Mac環境ということが伝わるようにos-xタグを付けてみました。

Comment: OSX が関係あることがわかりました。 (MBA だとブートローダの設定をいろいろ変更しなければいけないみたいです)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rEFInd を利用するとひとまず、ブートさせることには成功したので、共有します。

## 1. rEFInd をダウンロード

https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/ からダウンロード

## 2. Mac の SIP を無効化する

1. Mac を再起動
2. 起動音がなる前に Command+R を押してリカバリモード起動
3. 上のメニューバーから Utility -> Terminal 起動
4. `csrutil disable` 実行
5. Mac 再起動
6. (SIP が off のためか) grub の真っ黒い画面が表示されたが、`exit`を入力すると mac が start する

## 3. refind-install を実行する

ダウンロードしておいた zip の中にある インストーラーを叩いて指示に従うとインストールできました

## 4. Mac の SIP を有効化する

リカバリモードのターミナルで `csrutil enable`

## 5. Mac を再起動すると rEFInd の画面が表示され、 EFI の方を選択すると USB からでも ubuntu がブートする